# Show that a set E is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $X$. Show that the set

$E = \{ x\in X: \exists y \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ with } \lim_{n} f_{n}(x) = y \} $

is measurable.

My try:

If I have understood it correctly we need to show that $E \in \mathfrak{A}$. So first of all we know that $ \lim_{n} f_{n} $ is measurable.

Let $x' \in E$,  with $\lim_{n} f_{n}(x') = y'$, then

$ A = \{x \in X: \lim_{n} f_{n} = y' \} \in \mathfrak{A}$.

So for any $x' \in E$ we can create a subset of $E$ which belongs to $ \mathfrak{A} $.

Now let $A_{i} = \{x \in X \textrm{ and } x_{i} \in E: \lim_{n} f_{n}(x) = \lim_{n} f_{n}(x_{i}) \} $.

If $ \cup_{i} A_{i}$ is a countable union such that $E = \cup_{i} A_{i},$ then $E \in \mathfrak{A}$.

I don't really know if this is a valid approach and how to argue that E can be covered by a countable union. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A point $x$ belongs to $E$ if and only if $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges, hence if and only if $\{f_n(x)\}$ is Cauchy.

Let $n,m,k \ge 1$ and let $E_{n,m,k} = \{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < 1/k\}$.  Since $f_n$ and $f_m$ are measurable, so is $E_{n,m,k}$.  For each $N \ge 1$ define
$$
E_{N,k}=  \bigcap_{n,m \ge N} E_{n,m,k}
$$
so that $E_{N,k}$ is also measurable.  Your set $E$ is given by
$$
E = \bigcap_{k \ge 1} \bigcup_{N \ge 1} E_{N,k}
$$
so that $E$ is measurable too.

Answer (score 3):

A point $x$ belongs to $E$ if and only if $\{ f_n(x) \}$ converges, which happens if and only if $\limsup_n f_n(x)=\liminf_n f_n(x)$, which happens iff $\limsup_n f_n(x)-\liminf_nf_n(x)=0$. The functions $\limsup_n f_n,\liminf_n f_n$ are measurable, and so is their difference. Now:
$$E=\left( \limsup_n f_n-\liminf_n f_n \right)^{-1}[\{ 0 \}]$$

and the inverse image of a measurable set ($\{ 0 \}$) under a meaurable function, is measurable.